# Filling an array with integer multiples of a signal value

Tags: arrays, loops, vhdl

I have an array called amux, and I want to save integer multiples of signal `A` inside the array. The pseudocode below gives an idea:

```
amux(0) <= "00001101";
amux(1) <= amux(0);

....

amux(n) <= amux(n-1);
```

My full code looks like this:

```
-- n is 4 and m is 3, amux is an array, mzeros is 0's
regA: process(clk)
variable r : integer := 2**m;
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if ld_a = '1' then
            amux(0) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned((0),n*m+m));
            amux(1) <= mzeros & A;

            for i in 2 to r-1 loop 
              if (i mod 2) = 0 then
                   amux(i) <= amux(i/2)(n*m+m-2 downto 0) & '0';
                else
                  amux(i) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(amux(i-1))+unsigned(amux(1)));
                end if;
            end loop;

        end if;
    end if;
```

end process regA;

My current implementation outputs all "00000000"s, except for amux(0). What's the problem with my approach?

Comment: need more context : post a small complete compilable example.

Comment: Just guessing, but sounds like you expected the "00001101" to ripple through to all amux(1) .. amux(n).  However, that is not the way that `<=` works in VHDL, since the value assigned with `<=` to amux(0) is not visible until next simulation cycle, so the assign to amux(1) uses the current ("old") value of amux(0), which is probably all "00000000", and like wise for the remaining amux assigns.

Comment: i want to save integer multiples of signal A inside of the array

Comment: Signals are updated only at the end of a process. When you reference `amux` on the right side of the `<=` operator, you're getting the value that `amux` had when the process started and not any updates made along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we understand you correctly, the problem is that you cannot use a signal's value in a process immediately after you make an assignment to it. The assigned values will only be available after the process finishes. If this is what you intended to do, you can use a variable for that purpose. Variables have their value updated immediately.

The code example below should be close to what you want:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity array_loader is
    generic (
        N: integer := 4;
        M: integer := 3;
        DATA_WIDTH: integer := N * M + M;
        ARRAY_DEPTH: integer := 2**M
    );
    port (
        clk: in std_logic;
        ld_a: in std_logic;
        A: in unsigned(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture rtl of array_loader is
    type amux_type is array (0 to ARRAY_DEPTH-1) of unsigned(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal amux: amux_type;

begin
    regA: process(clk)
        variable multiple: unsigned(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if ld_a then
                multiple := to_unsigned(0, multiple);
                amux(0) <= multiple;

                for i in 1 to amux'high loop
                    multiple := multiple + A;
                    amux(i) <= multiple;
                end loop;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end;
```

Please note that the above code is valid VHDL-2008 only; in earlier versions, `ld_a` would have to be compared against '1' explicitly, and it wouldn't be possible to use the generic constants `N` and `M` to calculate the value of subsequent generics.

Comment: And getting the point is good, unfortunately the code example has four semantic errors, N and M aren't available in declaring DATA_WIDTH and ARRAY_DEPTH, ld_a isn't a boolean and to_unsigned is misused. (This question showed up as Related to a newer question).

Comment: @user1155120 I edited the question to mention that these are VHDL-2008 features.